# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, nonetype

```
def IsYearLeap(yr):
    if yr % 4 == 0 and (yr % 100 !=0 or yr % 400 == 0):
        return True
    return False

yr = print(int(input("The year is:")))
print(IsYearLeap(yr))
```

Why does this simple function produce an error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please be so kind and tell us which error you get. Is it an `Exception` or does the code not compile? In case of an `Exception`, which one? In case of a compiler error: what is the compiler output?

Answer (score 3):

`print` returns `None`. When you write

```
yr = print(int(input("The year is:")))
```

The number is given to `print`, it prints, then `print` returns `None`; and that's what is assigned to `yr` (check the value of `yr`).

Just move the `print` call so its return value isn't being assigned to anything.

```
yr = int(input("The year is:"))
print(yr)
print(IsYearLeap(yr))
```